# How does a Pareto efficient equilibrium scale for n individuals?

Tags: microeconomics, pareto-efficiency

Say I have a starting situation with Pareto efficient allocations between 2 individuals, now a third one comes in and changes the allocations. Now a fourth one, etc. Up untill a nth individual comes in. Do we now have to resolve (n-1) equations or n^(n-1) equilibria? How does the "difficulty" scale for n individuals? I don't know if that makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: It does not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing pairwise comparisons, then with $n$ individuals there will be $$\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} $$ such comparisons.  You can write this as $\binom{n}{2}$ or as $\frac12n^2-\frac12n$ if you prefer.

$1$ for two people, $3$ for three, $6$ for four and so on, known as [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: It makes sense thank you, I somehow thought every new allocation would change the older allocations so that there would a massive number of equilibria before you get to the final one.

Comment: @Henry It seems I am somewhat slow today. Having read the answer I still do not understand what the question was. Could you please explain?

Comment: @denesp Presumably to check Pareto optimality and equilibrium, you need to ensure there are no possible exchanges of allocations between pairs of individuals which make both happier.  I took the question to be how many such pairs there were to be checked, given there are $n$ individuals

Comment: @Henry I see. Thank you. On a side note: It is not enough to check pairs. Consider the case of three goods and three consumers with $U(x,y,z) = \min(x,y,z)$ and the initial distribution
$$
(3,0,0) \hskip 10pt (0,3,0) \hskip 10pt (0,0,3).
$$
Pairwise no improvements are possible but clearly they could all get $(1,1,1)$ which is better.

Comment: @denesp If you can compare multiples, then the answer is $1$ (just compare everybody together).

Comment: @Henry True, but this does not make pairwise comparison any good. I am voting to close the question as unclear. OP's comment "every new allocation would change the older allocations" also seems to be out of sync with your interpretation.